# Получение капчи с сайта

Tags: idhttp, delphi

Пытаюсь вытащить с сайта МТС их капчу. Но почему-то ничего не выходит. Почему?
Описание переменных:

```
  FS: TFileStream;
  textTableRecordId: integer;
  ImageNumber: integer;
  GetToMTSSite: string;
```

Сам код:

```
GetToMTSSite:=IdHTTP.Get('http://freesms.mts.by/cgi-bin/cgi.exe?function=sms_send&isFree=1');
textTableRecordId:=StrToInt(Copy(GetToMTSSite, Pos(GetToMTSSite, 'textTableRecordId')+40, 7));
if pos(GetToMTSSite, 'ImageNumber=')<>0 then
begin
 ImageNumber:=StrToInt(Copy(GetToMTSSite, Pos(GetToMTSSite, 'ImageNumber=')+11, 2));
 FS:=TFileStream.Create('captcha.jpg', FMCreate);
 IdHTTP.Get('http://freesms.mts.by/cgi-bin/cgi.exe?function=sms_show_antispam_image&ImageNumber='+IntToStr(ImageNumber));
 FS.Free;
 CaptchaImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('captcha.jpg');
end
else
begin
 ShowMessage('Не удаётся получить капчу с сайта.'+#13+'FATAL ERROR');
end
```

P.S. После GET-запроса результат имеет в себе такое содержимое как: `'textTableTecordId'` и `'ImageNumber='`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте отловить исключение: `Except
 on E:EIdHTTPProtocolException do
   ShowMessage(E.ErrorMessage);`

Comment: 'L 1.0 T' is not a valid integer value.

Comment: Хм, я понял свою ошибку!
Сейчас постараюсь поправить! :)